# how does the first snapshot gets evaluated

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

```
function sum(a,b) { return a+b;}

it("testing snapshot with sum",()=>{
  expect(sum(1,2)).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

How does the above test through error in case the test returns value other than 3 at first snapshot itself? I guess it compares relatively but I am not sure if it can be used where we know what's the exact value gonna be.

Comment: Doesn't `toMatchSnapshot()` do UI test?  Correct me if wrong.

Comment: yes it does ui testing

Comment: I am unable to connect the above piece of code and test with any UI functionality.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAuXJVI_bUs

Comment: Why not simply use `.toBe(3)`

Comment: @Albizia exactly my question . But please check in the above link the guy is using the toMatchSnapShot

Comment: What time in the video ? 
https://youtu.be/HAuXJVI_bUs?t=240 he is using toBe(3)

Comment: https://youtu.be/HAuXJVI_bUs?t=703

Comment: I guess he just wants to illustrate the use of jest snapshots. it happens it is possible to use it to compare integers. but that’s a bit overkill

Comment: so you are using that's gonna work too irrespective of overkiil

Comment: when it creates a snapshot it just saves doesn't matter the outcome right atleast for first snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be complete:

---

If Jest runs a snapshot test and no snapshot exists yet, it will create one.  From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing):

> On subsequent test runs Jest will simply compare the rendered output with the previous snapshot. If they match, the test will pass. If they don't match, either the test runner found a bug...or the implementation has changed and the snapshot needs to be updated.

Note that

> The snapshot artifact should be committed alongside code changes, and reviewed as part of your code review process.

Snapshot testing is *most commonly* used for UI code, but that doesn't mean it can *only* be used for UI code.

---

For the test you are describing, the first time the test runs it will create the snapshot with the value `3`.

It is up to you, as the developer, to make sure that value is correct and to check the snapshot in with your source code.

Ultimately that is the same process as checking that you passed the correct value of `3` into something like `.toBe(3)` and checking that assertion into your source code.

---

So yes, that is a valid way to test the function being tested.

Having said that, there is a lot more overhead for `toMatchSnapshot` than for something like `toBe` so for a simple test like this it makes sense to just use `.toBe(3)` instead of `.toMatchSnapshot()`.

Snapshot testing is most useful for complex values like UI that would bloat your test files if they were included inline and are challenging to update accurately.  With snapshot testing they are stored in a separate file and updates can be made easily by telling `Jest` to update the snapshot once the updated value has been verified to be correct.

Comment: I guess you are missing my point , I am saying how it is possible to say test passed or not (assuming passed successfully just because it isn't there early will itself make testing a blunder,isn't it ) in first snapshot unlike with tobe we can always whether it is failed or not.

Comment: @SaiRam I understand your question.  The first time it runs no snapshot exists so `Jest` will just tell you a snapshot got created.  It will never fail on the first run.  It is then up to you to confirm that the value `Jest` stores in the initial snapshot is correct.

Comment: so initally we have to check manually all the snapshots if they were true or not. Right ?

Comment: @SaiRam exactly.  You can see in the youtube link you shared that `Jest` reports a snapshot was created.  At that moment you would check to make sure the snapshot value is correct and add it to source control along with the snapshot test.  From then on anyone who downloads your tests will also get the snapshot file and the test will work as expected (failing if the result isn't `3`).

Answer (score 1):

Snapshot testing with [`toMatchSnapshot()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) is used to test the rendered UI, that is, the HTML of your components.

If you want to do a unit test and test the output of a function, you can use matchers suchs as `toEqual`, see this [doc about Jest matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers).

In your case:

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }

it("testing snapshot with sum", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
})
```